# Decoding QR Codes

Tags: javascript, ruby, qr-code

Does anyone know of any library (Ruby/JavaScript) that can DECODE QR codes from matrix (**without image recognition !**).

I have a 2D array of binary values holding a QR code (alphanumeric) that I want to decode into a string. (Must support error correction)

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you can use jruby, try exploring zxing which is a java library for decoding qr codes. Here is an example of how it can be used from ruby http://copypastel.com/story/QR_(de)Coding. Ofcourse this example does not deal with your specific use case but hopefully the zxing library does.

Comment: Can you post an example of a QR code in the format you have it?

Comment: [Here is a sample QR from google apis](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=100x100&chl=google.com&chld=H|0)

(Mine is encoded in a 2D array of booleans instead of a jpeg)

Answer (score 1):

ZXing can decode from pure data if you convert it/wrap it in a class that ZXing wants. I think you just need to implement/convert to the ZXing BitMatrix type. If the data is 1-to-1 with the qr modules (primitive black spots), you just need to call the decoder. If the data isn't 1-to-1 (more than one data point per qr module) you need to go through the detector first, which figures out how many data points there are per module.

There's a ruby gem for zxing at https://github.com/smparkes/zxing.rb that will use the C++ port via FFI for 1.8/1.9 and the Java port for jruby.